# Show progress bar while a file is being downloaded

Tags: php, ajax, cakephp

### Objective:

I'd like to show a progress bar while a file is being downloaded.

### What I've tried so far:

**AJAX code:**

```
    $.ajax({
            async: true,
            xhr: function() {
                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                console.log(xhr);
                xhr.addEventListener("progress", function (evt) {
                    if (evt.lengthComputable) { 
                        var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) *100;
                        $("div.progress > div.progress-bar").css({ "width": percentComplete + "%" }); 
                    } 
                },false);
            return xhr;
            }, 
            url: $("#CardExportCardsForm").attr('action'),
            data: $("#CardExportCardsForm").serialize(),
            success: function(data){
                //console.log(data);
            }


        });
```

**HTML code:**

Progress bar:

```
 <div class="progress"> 
    <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="0" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width: 0%;">
    </div> 
</div>
```

### Issue I'm facing:

The AJAX request is working perfectly. It's getting a success response and the file is being successfully.

But, it's not showing the download progress anywhere. I've even tried printing the percentComplete in the log, but to no avail.

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you sure you mean download, and not upload? You are sending form data to the server – so that would be an upload. Are you receiving a (large) file/resource from the server in response (that could be considered a “download” then)?

Comment: If you want to monitor the _upload_ progress of the form data, then you need to bind the `progress` handler to `XMLHttpRequest.upload`, see https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest#Monitoring_progress

Comment: It's not upload. Let me clear it up. My form data has a hidden field which contains a list of images, say img1, img2, img3..etc. Now, in the other page, I'm trying to retrieve all files with these names and then download the respective images in zip format.

Comment: What “other page”? And you don’t usually make _downloads_ via AJAX – because then you get the result _in_ your script only, it will not trigger a download dialog, because it is a background request.

Comment: In order for someone being able to help you, you'll have to at least show what your "action" is doing on the server side, and what your browser environment looks like (see the answer from @BharatJain).

Answer (score 0):

> The ProgressEvent.lengthComputable read-only property is a Boolean
>   flag indicating if the resource concerned by the ProgressEvent has a
>   length that can be calculated. If not, the ProgressEvent.total
>   property has no significant value.

It is not compatible with all browsers as you can check [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ProgressEvent/lengthComputable#AutoCompatibilityTable)